# How to configure tikz/pgfplots to align figure in paper

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following 8 eps figures, where the first 4 are generated using the following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
    -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" && %  or ;
   pdftops -eps "\image".pdf}}
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\MajorTickLength{
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length} * 0.5
}
\begin{axis}[y label style={at={(axis description                 
    cs:0.17,1)},anchor=south west,rotate=-90, font=\small},
    ylabel=Time, 
    legend style={draw=none, fill=none,font=\small, at={(axis 
    cs:1.6,0.25)},anchor=north west},
    legend cell align={left},
    width=8cm, height=5.5cm,
    xmin=1.4, xmax=18.6,
    ymin=-0.02, ymax=0.25,
    major tick length=\MajorTickLength,
    tick pos = left,
    ytick={0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20},
    xtick={2,4,6,8,10, 12,14,16, 18},
    ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
    xticklabels={ $200$,,$600$,,$1000$,, $1400$,, $1800$},
    yticklabels={$0\%$, $5\%$, $10\%$, $15\%$, $20\%$}]
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and the others are generated using

```
    \begin{axis}[y label style={at={(axis description                 
        cs:0.17,1)},anchor=south west,rotate=-90, font=\small},
ylabel=Time, 
legend style={draw=none, fill=none,font=\small, at={(axis cs:1.6,0.25)},anchor=north west},
legend cell align={left},
width=8cm, height=5.5cm,
xmin=1.4, xmax=18.6,
ymin=0, ymax=0.25,
major tick length=\MajorTickLength,
tick pos = left,
ytick={0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20},
xtick={2,4, 6,8,10,12, 14, 16,18},
ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
xticklabels={ $2 \times 10^4$,, $6 \times 10^4$,,$10 \times 10^4$,, $14 \times 10^4$, ,$18 \times 10^4$},
yticklabels={$0$, $500$, $1000$, $1500$, $2000$}]
```

The only difference is the labels of the ticks. When I include the figures in my paper, I find that
the figures do not align well. Specifically, the last 4 figures are shifted a little to the left.
[image]

The code to insert figures in the paper is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}  
\begin{figure*}[!th]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test1-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{A}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test1-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{A}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test1-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{A}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test1-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{A}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test2-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{B}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test2-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{B}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test2-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{B}}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.24\textwidth}
\centering
\epsfig{file=fig/test2-figure0.eps,scale=0.35}
\caption{\footnotesize{B}}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! How you insert this diagrams in your document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diagrams have different widths. In the second row you have wider y labels. The influence of this differences you can remove by adding option `[trim axis left]` to diagrams:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
```

[image]

For further help you need to provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document, which we can compile and observe, if you maybe have some mismatch also there.

**Addendum:**
I would include your images in the document on the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\MajorTickLength{
    \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/major tick length} * 0.5
}
\pgfplotsset{
    width=1.1\linewidth, height=.8\linewidth,
    legend style={draw=none, fill=none, font=\scriptsize,
                  legend pos=north west},
    legend cell align=left,
    tick pos = left,
    ticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize},
    major tick length=\MajorTickLength,
    ylabel=Time,
    y label style={at={(0.17,1)},
                   anchor=south west,rotate=-90, font=\footnotesize},
    ytick={0, 0.05,..., 0.20},
    xtick={2,4,..., 18},
    xmin=1.4,   xmax=18.6,
    ymin=0,     ymax=0.25,
           }

\pgfplotsset{% for the first row
    xticklabels={$200$,,$600$,,$1000$,,$1400$,,$1800$},
    yticklabels={$0\%$, $5\%$, $10\%$, $15\%$, $20\%$},
            }
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 1}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 2}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 3}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 4}
\end{subfigure}



\pgfplotsset{% for the secon row   
    xticklabels={$ 2{\times}10^4$,,$6{\times}10^4$,,$10{\times}10^4$,,
                 $14{\times}10^4$,,$18{\times}10^4$},
    xticklabel style = {font=\scriptsize, rotate=45, anchor=north east},
    yticklabels={$0$, $500$, $1000$, $1500$, $2000$}
            }
\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 5}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 6}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 7}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
\hspace*{2em}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[trim axis left]
\begin{axis}
  \addplot[mark=x] coordinates {
    (2, 0.02)
    (4, 0.04)
    (6, 0.06)
    (8, 0.08)
    (10, 0.10)
    (12, 0.12)
    (14, 0.14)
    (16, 0.16)
    (18, 0.18)
};
\legend{$\textsf{A}$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{diagram 8}
\end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As you can see:

- image code is included directly in document
- images have reduced font size
- x tick labels in the second row are rotated for 45 degrees (otherwise they overlap)
- images are not centered in `subfigure, however, they are shift with` \hspace*{2em}` to right

[image]

(red lines shows text area borders)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have added the code to insert the figures. I tried your solution. It seems not work because I generated the figures from separate files.

Comment: @Edward, sory, what you now add is not of big help. I ask you for MWE, a complete small document, which reproduce your problem. From (new) code fragments I see that you in document use .eps file of diagrams Why? Apparently you generate diagrams on separate files on the wrong way (you not provide any information, how you do this).

Comment: @Zarka Thanks. I have edited the question. Now the first piece of code is the document to generate test1-figure0.eps. The figure test2-figure0.eps is similarly generated using the second piece of code.  In the 3rd piece of code, I show the document where the figures are used.